# glFrameBuffer2D blending doesn't work

Tags: opengl, opengl-3

I'm having trouble with rendering to texture output from this opengl example: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Modern_OpenGL_Tutorial_Text_Rendering_01

My framebuffer is setup as follows:

```
glGenTextures(1, &back_text);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, back_text);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
glGenFramebuffersEXT(1, &font_buffer);
glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, font_buffer);
glFramebufferTexture2DEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, back_text, 0);
```

In best case I can get filled rectangle with color where letter should appear (it appears like alpha is always 1.0).
I've tried original example and it works correctly.

My question is: do I need to enable something to make this work or do I need to take different approach?

Edit:
It turns out that I need to use
 
glutInitContextVersion(2,0);
 instead of 
glutInitContextVersion(3,2); 
and world is happy place!! :)

Comment: Yes you do: `glEnable(GL_BLEND)`.

Comment: thnx glampert but that's not what I'm asking. I'm using exactly the same source code as in referenced article but instead of rendering directly to default framebuffer I render to texture and then draw that texture to default buffer. It's clearly blending problem since if I disable blending in original example I get what I have with blending enabled in my (render to texture) code.

Comment: Do you also _disable_ the blending while you render the frambuffer texture to the default framebuffer?

Comment: It's glut's error and I had to jump some serious hoops (by creating additional texture framebuffers and doing blending in shader). Please take a loot at edit of my original question for explanation.